# Rspec confused when I run the tests on the rspec with the --pattern and --exclude-patternn flags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I need to run all the tests from the "spec/workers/**" folder, but I don't want to run the tests in a specific folder that is inside the "spec/workers/". I'm using the `--pattern` flags to say what I want and `--exclude--pattern` to say what I don't want to run. and it still does what is described in `--exclude-pattern`.

Eg:

```
bundle exec rspec --pattern "spec/workers/**/*_spec.rb" --exclude-pattern "spec/workers/study_workers/*_spec.rb"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a bug but expected behavior.

When there are two filters defined, one to include a specific files and another to exclude the same specific files, then excluding pattern has a lower priority and therefore the file is included.

Please see the discussion in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/2548).